# How does one get docker running on Ubuntu 16 and remove old installs?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, docker

I had taken a course on a training site that first suggested using sudo apt-get install docker.io or docker-io.  The instructor then explained that this is an old method.  So, then, without mentioning removing that version, he says to add a repo and use sudo apt-get update followed by sudo apt-get install docker lxc-docker.  I saw the errors when I tried to see if it was running after this and to pull an image, not in that order - I mean I wouldn't try to pull if it wasn't running.

Anyway, I cannot seem to get it to start.  I got this error instead
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.  I setup a full gist to show the complete output.
First I should note, that I do have docker installed in /usr/bin/docker and while I don't see a lxc-docker there are files in there that seem to relate to docker and start with lxc.
The gist is at: https://gist.github.com/BruceMWhealton/0c6b84062b013d500089c5e22bf10462

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [installation on Ubuntu docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) have steps for this. Basically, add the current apt source:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main
```

Then update the cache and remove the old package:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker
```

Then you should be able to install the latest version - check with `docker version` and it will be (as of today) `1.12.1`.